# Trying to connect MySQL to my Node.js server, with no success

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to connect my Node.js (Express.js) server to MySQL. The thing is, it shows a stable connection in my MySQL workbench, however it just shows an error in the cmd in my VS Code when I try to connect the server there.

This doesn't make any sense, I even changed the database & password in my server.js code. But it said it couldn't find the db with that name. So what I did was uninstall the version of MySQL and installed the 8.0 version of MySQL that's supported by Workbench. I'd like to note that I have mysql2 npm package installed. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any help would be greate. I'll upload the screenshots of the messages on the Workbench and VSC. I'd copy/paste server.js here but it shows my db password.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWdob.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHTvP.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome:. Using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: I simply added these images so that those whoever answered my question would have a more clearing understanding of my issue. I don't like uploading either, but I'm not going to copy/paste my server.js file as that contains my MySQL DB login info

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, I currently don't have comment privileges that's why I am writing here.
The issue is that when you mention a `DB` in the `options` of `mysql2` connect method it will try to reach the mentioned host and connect to the MySQL at defined port. Then it will try to find the mentioned database. But it will not create an empty `Database` for you if it does not exist, rather it will throw an error which it is doing in your case.
You may:

- Either create a DB named `virtualdb` manually through `mysql cli` or MySQL Workbench.
- OR change the name of parameter from `vitualdb` to some existing database.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hate SO.How do I go the 'msql cli' method?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if it did this, because I installed another version of mysql. When I did this, it asked me to create a new password

Comment: Are you discord? I just feel like this will be a lot easier if we resolved this problem on that platform